# Post on a business page timeline

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I have read over many pages but just can't seem to find the correct way to post to a business facebook page. I can use the code below to post to my wall but unsure how to use this to post to a business page.

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();
$attachment = array(
    'message' => $_GET['message'],
);
// /me/feed/
$result = $facebook->api("/$user/feed/", 'GET', $attachment);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems getting app to post to a page](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9066941/problems-getting-app-to-post-to-a-page)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Graph Api - Posting to Fan Page as an Admin](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/3627684/facebook-graph-api-posting-to-fan-page-as-an-admin)

Answer (score 1):

If everyone resp. your precise user is allowed to post on their wall, then just set the id of the page in your API call instead of $user.

Otherwise you’ll have to get a [page access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#page_access_tokens) first, and use that in your API call.

Comment: BTW, User is always can post to pages he own, but page's `access_token` is needed if post should be owned by Page and not by posting User.

Comment: ah so instead of /$user/feed/ then use /ID/ for the page ID I want to insert text from php?

Comment: @RobertSaylor, yep, this should do the work as long as you have permissions to post to the destination page

Comment: Thanks! Will try tonight and post if that worked! I tend not to ask for help but facebook with PHP is new to me. I got twitter working if anybody needs help just ask :)